# How can I index/search + and - symbol in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I need to search the word "I+D", and my analyzer don't work with `+` (plus) and `-` (minus) symbols. How can I search it?

My personal analyzer:

```
 /**
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Hugo Zaragoza and Jose R. P�rez-Ag�era
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. Neither the name of copyright holders nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
 * TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR CONTRIBUTORS
 * BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;


import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.StopFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer;

/**
 * Spanish Lucene analyzer
 * @author Hugo Zaragoza and Jose R. P�rez-Ag�era
 */
public class SpanishAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

    private Set stopSet;

    /**
     * Creates the Lucene Spanish Analyzer
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public SpanishAnalyzer() throws IOException {
        super();
        stopSet = StopFilter.makeStopSet(loadStopWords());
    }

    /** Constructs a {@link StandardTokenizer} filtered by a {@link
    StandardFilter}, a {@link LowerCaseFilter} and a {@link StopFilter}. */
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
        result = new StandardFilter(result);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
        result = new StopFilter(result, stopSet);
        result = new SpanishStemmerFilter(result);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the spanish stop-words list
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static String[] loadStopWords() throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("stopwords-spanish.txt");
        //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/becario/Escritorio/CVTKAxel/lib/stopwords-spanish.txt");
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (line != null) {
            list.add(line.trim());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String stopWords[] = new String[list.toArray().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.toArray().length; i++) {
            stopWords[i] = (String) list.get(i);
        }

        return stopWords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you perform search operation in your code?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "it don't work"? The analyzer should be able to handle these characters normally. Are you referring to the QueryParser perhaps? If so, you can bypass it and create a Query, e.g., a [TermQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html), manually.

```
Query q = new TermQuery(new Term("field", "I+D"));
```

Or are you referring to the fact that the StandardTokenizer splits tokens on non-word characters (e.g. a '+' or '-')? If so, you could simply use a different one (e.g. a [WhitespaceTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceTokenizer.html)) or implement your own.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I want separate the tokens by space, and I implement this in my analyzer, but still doesn't work.
I change this line of my analyzer:
TokenStream result = new StandardTokenizer(reader);
to this:
TokenStream result = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);

And no search for "I+D", for example.
Thanks for response.

Comment: Well, I have the problem I think, I don't call the method that have this lines of code.
But I need pass a String and a Reader, from my index.java, and from my search.java classes, right?
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader)
I don't know how. I go to google for search examples.
I will say my progress :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I solved the problem with this code:
FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream("stopwords-spanish.txt");
byte[] b2 = new byte[file2.available()];
file2.read(b2);
file2.close();
String plainText2 = new String(b2);
String[] p = plainText2.split(" ");
Analyzer analyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer("Spanish", p);

without my older analyzer...

Thanks for response Duke and maks. :)

Comment: Happy to help. But, from the looks of it, you could've sufficed with replacing `new StandardTokenizer(reader)` with `new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader)`. What do you mean by _And no search for "I+D", for example_? Am I missing something?